# Nodemailer emails not being received by Gmail or Yahoo

Tags: node.js, email, gmail, yahoo, nodemailer

Nodemailer works fine when sending to email addresses on multiple different domains I own however mail sent to Gmail and Yahoo accounts are failing to be received. There are no errors from Nodemailer.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport");
var transporter= nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host : "box830.bluehost.com",
    secureConnection : true,
    port: 26,
    auth : {
        user : "email@domain.com",
        pass : "password123"
    }
}));

var contact = function(req,res){

        req.body = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
        var mailOptions={
            from : 'email@domain.com',
            to : 'email@gmail.com',
            subject : "New Message",
            text : 'Message text'
        };


        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error){
            if(error){
                console.log("error--" + error);
                res.send(error);
            }else{
                res.send('ok');
            }
        });
    }
```

Bluehost email is being used as the transporter. It's unlikely to be a spam/blacklisting issue because nothing is showing up in spam and I can send from/to the same accounts using Outlook. Using mxtoolbox.com it doesn't appear to be on any blacklists. Any ideas?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? their issues section on github is closed

Comment: check this solution, it might work: [problem with receiving nodemailer emails in yahoo and gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401433/8898138)